# Does this `last` output from macOS terminal describe a remote access login to my computer?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, security, malware

My computer was up to some strange things. I used the "last" command to check login activity and this is the result. Not only have I never seen it before this, all of my previous logins were missing, as you can see.

```
Last login: Wed Aug  3 03:35:37 on ttys001
/Library/Application\ Support/Apple/Remote\ Desktop/Notify
 ; exit; 
Jason@workstation ~ % /Library/Application\ Support/Apple/Remote\ Desktop/Notify
 ; exit;

[Process completed]
```

Is this something I should be concerned about or a sign my machine was compromised or remotely accessed?

Comment: This doesn't show the output of `last`, it rather looks as if the startup files of your shell have an error and immediately terminate the shell again. In this state, you can't even run `last`. So, before any further analysis, you should fix the startup file of your shell (probably `~/.zshrc`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are logged in to the shell. I'm also assuming your prompt looks as it should. I'm also assuming that other commands don't give a similar result.

That almost certainly isn't the output of `last`. You may have a script in your path or an alias in your `.zshrc` file. It could even be something in your prompt.

Try `which last` which should tell you if either of first two are true. The correct output from it should be `/usr/bin/last`.

You could even try the complete path yourself :- `/usr/bin/last` Now what do you get?

I would also not try and be smart with command line options, I would run the command with none.

Answer (score 1):

Something is executing the Apple-created shell script `/Library/Application\ Support/Apple/Remote\ Desktop/Notify`. That script then runs, does what it was told to do, and then exits your shell once it's finished. If this happens each time you manually open up a new terminal window then I must guess that executing this script has been placed in your shell initialization files (.profile, .bash_profile, .zshrc, etc.)

Or perhaps the `Notify` script has inadvertently been added to your normal Login Items within the System Settings -> General.

This 'last login' output is coming from the login DB (perhaps /var/log/utx.log depending on your OS version). It's telling you that that last login was a local connection from your terminal app connecting to the special character device named `ttys001`.

If it was a remote incoming connection via SSH or such then the output would instead reference the source IP address. It would appear more like:

```
Last login: Mon Jan 01 02:34:56 2024 from 257.258.259.260
```

You can use the `/usr/bin/last` to list all of the opened and recorded shell sessions. `last -w` is my typical execution but there are many different options and arguments available.

It's not unusual that the content of the last login DB is rotated on a monthly basis. If you're an infrequent shell user that might explain why you don't see prior shell sessions when running `last`.